# Pass a Point Node trought a database

Tags: anylogic

I want to create a population of agents directly from a database. I need to pass to each agents some parameters like: ID, Node, Number of access.
The ID and number of acces are easy, i just read a String and Double column, but I'm not able to pass the Point Node cause when I try to create a column of type "Point Node" I see an error sayng "type not found, user lacks privileges". Is there a way to pass also a Node or a Resource in a database?
Thaks for your answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PointNode is a specific object that you can define in AnyLogic, but how can you define a point node in a database? You can't.

What you have to do instead, is have a collection of point nodes in your model with a particular id and in your database you would have the id of that point node. then you would have a variable of type PointNode in your agent that initializes using the id of the pointNode parameter.

You can have all your pointnodes for example in a LinkedHashMap collection with the key being the id, and the value being the pointNode

Then your pointNode variable in the agent would have as initial value:
collection.get(pointNodeParameter)